# How to redirect the url passing of a file when making a request to folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, php-7

I am having a folder structure something like this, this is the root folder.

```
|__modules
     |_printData
     |_getData
```

I have a sidebar.php file in which I have made an anchor tag with link `modules/getData`

Whenever i click on that link my URL appears something like this which is acceptable according to logic.

```
www.example.com/modules/getData
```

What I am trying to achieve is, how to make the code work still but the URL should be something like this, i don't want the modules folder displayed in URL

```
www.example.com/getData
```

Even if someone accesses the method via direct URL it should be acceptable

Answer (score -1):

You can use mod-rewrite

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule !module /module%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

This will internally forward **/getData** to **/module/getData** .

Comment: The code you provided will work only for /module/getData what if there are multiple files then I will have to write a number of lines. Is there a way to modify the code so that any file request made to that folder is handled.

Comment: By default your code is redirecting to that page for default no other files are accessible even I access other files same output is shown which resided in getData.php